# WPF UI to allow user to build a complex query and output an Expression Tree

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, expression-trees

What I am about to do build is a UI that will allow a power user to build complex queries.

This is non-trivial, but very common. So before I re-invent the wheel, I would like to see if anybody can point me to some already-written free code or release some of their own.

#### Required:

To be able to specify some 'where-clause' type logic like this: `Age>21 and (Citizen=True or HasGreeCard=True)` but without having to type the query code, instead, use a UI with constrained options and on-the-fly syntax checking (e.g., no unclosed parenthesis or ending a term with an Operator).

I've seen this type of thing in many line-of-business apps, where you can say 'add condition' and another line appears on the UI like this:

```
 Dropdown of fields     Dropdown of ops (=, >, etc)     Blank box for entry
```

And you can add more lines, and the lines are all and'ed, but you can also decide to OR a few, or insert parenthesis (explicity or via indenting), NOT a line, insert, delete, and move lines around, etc.

#### Not required but nice:

- WPF - I could convert from winforms.
- Extensibility using OO constructs.
- Validate the sanity of the query.
- Emit a `System.Linq.Expressions` expression tree - or similar data structure.
- If it attempts to execute the query I don't need that; but I don't mind removing it.

Comment: I did something like that in WPF a few months back. I looked around for existing systems and then gave up and build my own. It took a while, but I was very happy with the result :)

Comment: I had the same experience as Rachel, not much out there for free that I could find.

Comment: @Rachel - Is the code on your blog? I snooped around a bit and didn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: @FastAl Sorry, it's not. The code was for some custom software, and I don't want to post it without asking their permission first. I was quite proud of it though... IT staff could build "query pieces" and users could drag/drop those pieces into SELECT, WHERE, or ORDER BY areas. I have a sketch of the UI if you want: http://www.mediafire.com/?7ve6ww61rgjr25d

Answer (score 0):

This problem was already solved by DevExpress controls. Google their FilterControl for wpf. It can be easily ajusted to your needs, you can add and remove operations, and after that convert expressions to SQL query or implement ivisitor and perform equations or other generation...